# CSS Modules and multiple class names with tags

Tags: css-modules, react-css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

What do I do when I run across this?

```
<div className="ui row myClass">
```

If myClass was the only class I would import the relevant style sheet and do this:

```
<div className={styles.myClass}>
```

This syntax does not work (not surprising) and I am not sure what to do:

```
<div className="ui row" {styles.myClass}>
```

Should I just boil it down to a class without tag selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood you, but if I got you right, what I'd do is simply using template literals, like so:

```
<div className={`ui row ${styles.myClass}`}>
```

Take into account, in the end, React components are just JS. That's the beauty of them. Just remember: now any JS expression, like props, etc., has to be with $ sign (between `${}` instead of just `{}`).

Comment: This is the normal way of doing it, there are libraries like "classNames" that assist you in completing this task.

Comment: what would the syntax look like with classNames?